# my TableViewController is stuck (beginner)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

This code is in my TableViewController and when I simulate it, the cells load with the right content, but the view can't be scrolled or clicked on. I put a prinln() in didSelectRowAtIndexPath and it didn't even log. When would this happen?

This my code in viewDidLoad

```
    super.viewDidLoad()


    var query = PFUser.query()
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({

     (objects: [AnyObject]! , error: NSError!) in

     self.users.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

        for object in objects {
            var user: PFUser = object as PFUser
            var isfollowing:Bool = false
            if user.username != PFUser.currentUser().username{
            self.users.append(user.username)


                var query = PFQuery(className: "followers")
                query.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser().username)
                query.whereKey("following", equalTo: user.username)
                query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ ( objects:[AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        for object in objects {
                            isfollowing = true
                        }
                        self.following.append(isfollowing)

                    }
                   self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
```

the code for filling in the table cells are very basic with returning a count of an array and textlabel being set as array[indexPath.row].

THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just stick with the standart delegates from `UITableView`..

Create a table in the storyboard and create a default cell with an identifier. Connect the `ViewController` as the delegate of the table.

After you did that fill the array cells with the array you have.

example:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return userArray.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("objectCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    var user:User            = userArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as User

    var imageView:UIImageView   = cell.viewWithTag(1) as UIImageView
    var ageLbl:UILabel          = cell.viewWithTag(2) as UILabel
    var nameLbl:UILabel         = cell.viewWithTag(3) as UILabel

    nameLbl.text                = user.name
    ageLbl.text                 = user.age
    imageView.image             = user.Image

    return cell
}
```